# Reinstall system app which is uninstalled for the current user?

Tags: installation, system-apps

*I have already posted this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/bc0l4n/reinstall_system_app_which_is_uninstalled_for_the/ekp70fc/?context=3), but I might reach a better audience here.*

---

I "uninstalled" Google Play Games using [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) guide by XDA. Now I need to reinstall it. This is the command, how I should be able to reinstall the app: `adb shell cmd package install-existing <name of package>`. But there is one problem: My phone is on Android Lollipop, and the command doesn't exist there. I manually tried to install the apk back, with adb and with the normal package installer. The Settings app always says something like "Not installed for user" (translated from another language).

So I have 2 questions:

1. In which Android version was this command introduced?
2. How can I get this app back?

PS: I have root access, but would prefer a non-rooted solution.

Comment: @Firelord dumpsys (Play Store): https://pastebin.com/bCApNT0S path (Play Store): package:/data/app/com.android.vending-1/base.apk  
dumpsys (Play Games): https://pastebin.com/2r9y7kQp path (Play Games): (Empty)

Comment: My apologies. I got confused with Play Store. Instead of using system app path, can you try with this: `adb shell pm install -r --user 0 /data/app/com.google.android.play.games-1/*.apk`. I tried this approach on Google Calendar app on Oreo and it worked, that's why I am suggesting this.

Comment: @Firelord it says 'Success', but still 'Not installed for user' in Settings. Damn, I got a headache from this. Screenshot [here](https://prnt.sc/nbpiy6).

Comment: Last resort would be a factory reset. But looking at the help of the `cmd` command, it might be worth trying `adb shell "cmd package compile --reset com.google.android.play.games"`. Also, though I doubt it works it cannot hurt: `pm enable --user 0 <pkg>`, `pm unhide --user 0 <pkg>`.

Comment: In XDA developers forum, I found that the command `adb shell cmd package install-existing <name of package>` can reinstall an uninstalled system app for the current user. But, when I tried it in my Android 7.0 smartphone, it showed an error that the command `install-existing` could not be found. Can this command be modified to get some result?

Comment: `pm enable --user 0` worked for me! thanks!

Comment: for me `cmd package install-existing` inside adb shell worked

Answer (score 1):

First, enable the package by using `pm enable --user 0 <pkg>`, and then install it by using `cmd package install-existing <pkg>`.