# Can't reinstall an app uninstalled through ADB

Tags: adb, installation, huawei, gallery

I recently got a Huawei P30 and used adb to remove some preinstalled apps I didn't want to use. I went a bit too far and removed the system gallery app (`com.android.gallery3d`) which turns out to be problematic for multiple things, such as opening taken pictures directly from the camera app.

I've tried reinstalling it but I'm facing multiple issues:

- When trying to install the APK that's still on the phone in `/system/priv-app/Gallery2`, I get a `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` error. The full error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl30820468.tmp/base.apk: /data/app/vmdl30820468.tmp/base.apk: File res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/img_patten_7.jpg in manifest does not exist]
```

- When trying to install a version I found online, I get a `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE`, which is odd as the app is supposed to be uninstalled. It doesn't appear in `pm list packages`, however running `dumpsys package com.android.gallery3d` does give a result, and the version is indeed more recent than the one I'm trying to install (9.1.1.309 vs 9.0.15.355). Using the `-d` flag when installing doesn't help as it's not a debug app. I couldn't find a more recent version online.

Is there a way to reinstall this app that doesn't involve a factory reset? Alternatively, is there a way to install a different version of it? It seems like `com.android.gallery3d` is a generic package name, I wouldn't be against having the "stock" Android one.

Comment: When the APK is still in `/system/priv-app/*`, the app isn't uninstalled. Are you sure you didn't just disable it? What command did you use to uninstall via ADB?

Comment: I used `adb uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.gallery3d`. Trying to run it again results in a `not installed for 0` error (with or without the `-k` flag). Not specifying the user also gives an error, `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR`

Comment: That only uninstalled it for that one user, but leaves the APK there (theoretically, a second user could still run it). Have you tried `adb shell "pm install -r <package.apk>" (replacing `<package.apk>` by the path to the installed APK file) or, if you have it on your PC, `adb install -r <APKfile>`? The important thing is the `-r` (re-install even if its there).

Comment: The `-r` flag doesn't help, same issues with both methods (apk left on the device and the one I downloaded)

Comment: That's ugly. Just guessing: what happens when you introduce the `--user 0` here as well? Then it can neither claim a wrong version nor that it's already there. If that doesn't work either, please try `pm default-state app.name` (taken from [this XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78233624&postcount=17)). I've never had that situation.

Comment: Specifying `--user 0` when installing didn't help. I added the full error to the question when trying with the app on the phone as it doesn't seem to be related with the current state of the app but rather with the apk itself. `pm defaul-state` says `Package com.android.gallery3d new state: default` but doesn't seem to have any effect (app still isn't visible anywhere, even after rebooting the phone)

Comment: Can you please upload the APK that resides in `/system/priv-app/Gallery2` somewhere and share the link with us? I want to try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636452/4720957) could be a problem with the APK.

Comment: Sure: https://send.firefox.com/download/69b457af2b74203a/#N9qa8vc7beaD67xCnc_lDQ (expires after 7 days or 100 downloads, I can reupload it if needed). Note that this APK is the one that was already residing in the phone, not the one I downloaded. I just tried signing it but I get the same error as before (`INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` because a file is missing in `res/drawables...`). I also tried bumping the downloaded one's version code using `apktool` and signing it myself but I get rejected as the signature isn't the same as the "existing" version.

Comment: @Jukurrpa looks like your problem is the same as: [Reinstall System app which is uninstalled for the current user?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210315/16575) Unfortunately, that is not solved there either, and overlaps with what I asked you to try here (Firelord pointed me to that one, thanks again!)

Comment: Wow thanks for the link to this question, `adb shell cmd package install-existing com.android.gallery3d` worked! I wasn't aware of that command. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great! And thanks for reporting back. Now that you confirmed, I've made that an answer. Though the comment chain here now is obsolete *for you* I suggest we leave it stay. All those "possibilities" might come in handy for someone else. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution can be found in the *question* [Reinstall System app which is uninstalled for the current user?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210315/16575) (which is unanswered):

```
adb shell cmd package install-existing com.android.gallery3d
```

Note this doesn't work in Android 5 (hence the other question), as the `cmd` command was only added later (I don't remember exactly when, but it's available in Android 7 at least).

Comment: And you can uninstall it with ```adb shell cmd package uninstall com.android.gallery3d```